# No real Polish keyboard iBus

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus

I am using Polish in `iBus`. I'm using `iBus` after my keyboard layout went crazy and changed randomly with application (even by fixing the options `globally`, `per window`, `each application`).

Well, there is no Polish keyboard. It's English! How to fix this?

The output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current` is 
`[('xkb', 'de'), ('xkb', 'us')]` and of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current` `uint32 0`.

Comment: To start with, let's figure out exactly which keyboard layout you are using. Please edit your question and show us the output of the commands `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` and `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current`

Comment: I see no Polish there - I see German and English (US), and your current keyboard layout is German. So you'd better open _System Settings -> Text Entry_ and add a Polish keyboard layout. This is some general info about dealing with input sources: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I see. I logged in once in Gnome and I should have activated those languages. I don't know how XFCE used that. So I came back to gnome to make those changes. I still wonder why I should have installed the whole of the language packets for Polish, if I only want to use the keyboard (with other input-sources managers it was possible).  But thank you, that solved the problem.

Comment: Since you didn't mention which desktop environment you have, I assumed Ubuntu with Unity. (Think Ubuntu GNOME sets the keyboard layout in the same manner; don't know about XFCE.) There is no need to install the complete language support for Polish if you just want to use a keyboard layout. What made you think otherwise?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson In gnome I had a list of languages for layout. Only German and English were on the list. The search results for Polish were null, and asking "install" (what I supposed, it referred to the layout) installed all the language. But it's ok. Now it works, that's the main thing. Thanks.